# Android Studio can't find package or symbol

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem when I have move some source code from package 
com.a.b **To** com.a.c.
After move I build project and found error:
Error:(11, 36) error: package com.x.y does not exist
Error:(113, 13) error: cannot find symbol class MyClass
(com.x.y -> all my package in my project).

I also search on GG or SO. then I try some ways:

1. Clearn -> Rebuild Prj;
2. File -> Invalidate cache.
3. Clean project -> re-open android studio.

I ensure all  module library have plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

**Notes:** AndroidStudio not show error when open class error. (Everything seem ok. It's only error when build).

Please help.
Thanks !

Comment: Manually delete all the import statements from your Java files. Android Studio will then automatically do the necessary imports for you again. See if that works for you.

Comment: @BidhanA It's still error when build :|